# Binding usercontrols Datacontext in DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatemplate, datacontext

I have two usercontrols inside of a TabItem. The TabItem has it's own ViewModel, which has a property that the TabItem's child ContentControl's content bound to. This property represents another viewmodel, which will change the view depending on which one it is. Here's an example:

```
<TabItem DataContext="{Binding Path=MainLayerTabViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}" Header="Layers">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ChildViewModel}">
        <ContentControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LayersViewModel}">
                <views:LayersTabView DataContext="{Binding ChildViewModel}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:UserDrawnLayersViewModel}">
                <views:AlternateLayersTabView DataContext="{Binding ChildViewModel}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.Resources>
    </ContentControl>
```

Here's the view model used as the datacontext for the tabitem:

```
public class MainLayerTabViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public object ChildViewModel { get; set; }

    public MainLayerTabViewModel()
    {
        ChildViewModel = (App.Current.Resources["ViewModelLocator"] as ViewModelLocator).LayersViewModel;
    }
}
```

Now, the two types of possible ViewModels for the `ChildViewModel` are `LayersViewModel` and `UserDrawnLayersViewModel`. When I change `ChildViewModel` to one of those, the view is properly switched via the `DataTemplate`. But the `DataContext` isn't actually being set. Nothing is being bound. I tried creating separate properties for each ViewModel in the MainLayerTabViewModel and binding the `DataContext` of each view to its own property, but that didn't work either.

Comment: How is `LayersViewModel` implemented? Does it have a `ChildViewModel` property? Shouldn't the `DataContext` of a `LayersTabView` be the `LayersViewModel` itself? Then you should remove `DataContext="{Binding ChildViewModel}"`.

Comment: Yup that was it! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't verified this, however I can see couple of issue with your code.

View should be

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ChildViewModel}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LayersViewModel}">
            <views:LayersTabView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:UserDrawnLayersViewModel}">
            <views:AlternateLayersTabView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainLayerTabViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewModelBase ChildViewModel { get; set; }

    public MainLayerTabViewModel()
    {
        ChildViewModel = new LayersViewModel();
        //or ChildViewModel = new UserDrawnLayersViewModel();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: That was it! Once I removed the `DataContext` from the DataTemplates it worked. Thanks!